# How do graphics libraries work?

Tags: opengl, directx, graphics

I have made many different game engines with OpenGL, but still struggle to understand how they work and the process in which the library tells the computer what to do.

How do graphics libraries such as DirectX or OpenGL work?

Comment: Please note that a quick answer does not mean a good answer. I think with more time we could get much higher quality answers to this sort of question.

Comment: Graphics libraries work like any other library: they are just a bunch of code that calls other code, in other libraries, the OS, or in a driver (for the GPU in this case). Is there a specific aspect of this process you want to know about?

Comment: @Gnemlock ok, i see your point, what would you like me to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Neither DirectX nor OpenGL is a graphics library.**

This is important to understand: neither is actually responsible for drawing graphics.

Instead how they work is that they provide an *interface* between your program and your graphics hardware.

Your graphics hardware is what actually does the drawing, so what DirectX or OpenGL do is provide a hardware-independent way for your program to tell the graphics hardware what to draw.

In summary:

- Your program issues drawing commands using DirectX or OpenGL.
- Your DirectX or OpenGL driver takes those commands, converts them to something that your hardware can understand, and passes them on to your hardware.
- Your hardware does the actual drawing.

Comment: quick response! But, thank you very much, It was silly of me to think of it like that. Just in-case you are wondering, i got the graphics library thing, from when i was learning java, from some guy who must have of thought about it like the way i did, but thank you very much for your response. :)

Comment: But one question, the library has the methods, so, technically, wouldn't the library be drawing, but the programmer is just calling?

Comment: The GL in OpenGL literally stands for "Graphics Library". -1 for clarity

Comment: @Type10, I would say he got it from the fact that its literally *named* a graphic library (**Open** **G**raphic **L**ibrary)

Comment: I think that if thought this way, there are no graphics libraries in the world. Not even math libraries, as it's the CPU that does the math.

Comment: @Gnemlock - look at paragraph 1, sentence 1 of any OpenGL spec: "OpenGL is a software interface/API to graphics hardware".

Comment: By my definition, that makes it a *library*. Admittedly, my definition of API might not be standard, but your completely failing to address the fact that it literally called *Graphics Library*.

Comment: @Gnemlock - was there really that much mileage for you in splitting hairs over terminology?